# How are the virial equations of state (not the co-efficients !) for gases derived?

Tags: thermodynamics, virial-theorem

Virial Equations of the form for real gases :

$$Z = 1 + BP + CP^2 ...  $$

$$Z=1+B/v+C/v^2...$$

I see these equations on many sites and textbooks, but I can't find from where they come. The closest I came to is: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236233782_Heike_Kamerlingh_-_The_Virial_Equation_of_State

I didn't understand this paper much since I'm not much into maths/physics, I'm a chemistry student.

In the above paper, equations 14 & 15, the virial equation was 'derived' from the van der Waal's equation but it was 'changed' when data did not fit in.

In the derivation of (14), why has the $b/V$ term $(1/8vL)$ in the van der Waal's equation been neglected when we're talking about a non-ideal gas?

I'm not asking for derivations for coefficients in the virial equations, only asking how were the equations formulated? Does it have more to do with the  physics part?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Wikipedia article on virial expansions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_expansion). This seems to give a pretty good explanation of why and how we use virial expansions.

Comment: @JohnRennie, i did look at it, my question is how can the p/RT(rho) be expanded as a power series in (rho) ..? i understood how the van der waal can be expanded ... is that where the virial equation comes from, from van der waal equation ?

Comment: It's mathematical.  It's an expansion in a McLauren series.

Comment: yes, i wanted to know whether it's a McLauren series expansion from the van der waal's equation .... & according to the original paper by Onnes, (http://www.dwc.knaw.nl/DL/publications/PU00014258.pdf) it appears to be so  ..!! i think i've got the answer !